# System performance is extremely laggy when copying and extracting files

Tags: gnome, hard-drive, performance, ssd, samsung

After a clean install of Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 (64-bit) and the according Gnome 3 (stable) [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) my system (Samsung [900X3C](http://www.samsung.com/de/consumer/notebooks-displays/notebook-computers/serie-9/NP900X3C-A03DE-spec)) is extremely laggy, when files are copied to the external hard-drive (HDD) or archives are extracted on my SSD ([Crucial M4 mSATA 256 GB](http://www.techspot.com/review/571-crucial-m4-msata-ssd/)). The mouse pointer acts very choppy, so does the whole Gnome Shell. It gets better, when files are copied within the SSD, but the slowdown is clearly perceivable. This also occurs, when files are downloaded with high speed (around 8 Mb/s) from the Internet. I don't know if this has to do with the same issue, but Firefox is also laggy, especially the scrolling, when tabs are loading. Also HD Video in VLC is sometimes choppy too, even with hardware decoding enabled.

I suspect, that the hard-drive is root of the problem, but what exactly is causing this slowdown? Using different schedulers (noop, deadline, cfq) didn't help. It also doesn't make a difference, if the notebook is on battery or connected to a power supply.

All hints and suggestions to solve this issue are desperately appreciated!

Here is the /etc/defaul/tlp of TLP, a power savings tool, mabye this will help:

```
--- TLP 0.5 --------------------------------------------

+++ Configured Settings: /etc/default/tlp
TLP_ENABLE=1
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_AC=0
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT=2
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_AC=15
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT=60
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC=0
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT=1
NMI_WATCHDOG=0
DISK_DEVICES="sda sdb sdc sdd"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="255 255"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="255 255"
DISK_IOSCHED="deadline cfq cfq cfq"
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC=max_performance
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT=min_power
PCIE_ASPM_ON_AC=performance
PCIE_ASPM_ON_BAT=powersave
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_AC=high
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT=low
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_AC=performance
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_BAT=battery
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_AC=auto
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_BAT=auto
WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=1
WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=5
WOL_DISABLE=Y
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC=0
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=1
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER=Y
BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT=0
BAY_DEVICE="sr0"
RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=on
RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=auto
RUNTIME_PM_ALL=1
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1
USB_BLACKLIST_WWAN=1
RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=0

+++ System Info
System         = SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD. 0.1 900X3C/900X3D/900X3E/900X4C/900X4D
BIOS           = P10ABK
Release        = Ubuntu 13.10
Kernel         = 3.11.0-19-generic x86_64
/proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-19-generic root=UUID=271463cd-ca74-46fa-9ce3-0de5a5aecec7 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7

+++ System Status
TLP power save = enabled
power source   = battery

+++ Processor
CPU Model      = Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3317U CPU @ 1.70GHz

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = ondemand
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   782000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 1701000 1700000 1600000 1500000 1400000 1300000 1200000 1100000 1000000 900000 800000 782000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = ondemand
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   782000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 1701000 1700000 1600000 1500000 1400000 1300000 1200000 1100000 1000000 900000 800000 782000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = ondemand
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   782000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 1701000 1700000 1600000 1500000 1400000 1300000 1200000 1100000 1000000 900000 800000 782000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = ondemand
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   782000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 1701000 1700000 1600000 1500000 1400000 1300000 1200000 1100000 1000000 900000 800000 782000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost                  = 1
/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog                          = 0

+++ Undervolting
PHC kernel not available.

+++ Temperatures
CPU temp               =    48 [°C]
Fan speed              = (not available)

+++ File System
/proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode               =     2
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs =  6000
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs    =  6000
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio               =    20
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio    =    10
/proc/sys/fs/xfs/age_buffer_centisecs  = (not available)
/proc/sys/fs/xfs/xfssyncd_centisecs    = (not available)
/proc/sys/fs/xfs/xfsbufd_centisecs     = (not available)

+++ Storage Devices
/dev/sda:
          Model     = M4-CT256M4SSD3                          
          Firmware  = 07MH    
          APM Level = none/disabled
          Status    = active/idle
          TRIM      = supported
          scheduler = deadline

        SMART info:
            5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct     =        0 
            9 Power_On_Hours            =     5332 [h]
          173 Wear_Leveling_Count       =       99 [%]
          194 Temperature_Celsius       =        0    [°C]


+++ SATA Aggressive Link Power Management
/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy  = min_power
/sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy  = min_power
/sys/class/scsi_host/host2/link_power_management_policy  = min_power
/sys/class/scsi_host/host3/link_power_management_policy  = min_power
/sys/class/scsi_host/host4/link_power_management_policy  = min_power
/sys/class/scsi_host/host5/link_power_management_policy  = min_power

+++ PCIe Active State Power Management
/sys/module/pcie_aspm/parameters/policy = default (using bios preferences)

+++ Intel Graphics
/sys/module/i915/parameters/powersave        =  1 (enabled)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/i915_enable_rc6  = -1 (use per-chip default)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/i915_enable_fbc  = -1 (use per-chip default)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/lvds_downclock   =  0 (disabled)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/semaphores       = -1 (use per-chip default)

+++ Wireless
bluetooth = off (software)
wifi      = on
wwan      = none (no device)

wlan0(iwlwifi): power management = on

+++ Audio
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save            = 1
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller = Y

+++ Battery Status
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/manufacturer                   = SAMSUNG Electronics
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/model_name                     = (not available)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/cycle_count                    =    578
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_full_design             =   5880 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_full                    =   4600 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_now                     =   4048 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/current_now                    =    932 [mA]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status                         = Discharging

+++ Runtime Power Management
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/power/control = auto (0x060000 Host bridge)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/power/control = auto (0x030000 VGA compatible controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.0/power/control = auto (0x078000 Communication controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1b.0/power/control = auto (0x040300 Audio device)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.0/power/control = auto (0x060400 PCI bridge)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.3/power/control = auto (0x060400 PCI bridge)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.4/power/control = auto (0x060400 PCI bridge)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1d.0/power/control = auto (0x0c0320 USB controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.0/power/control = auto (0x060100 ISA bridge)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/power/control = auto (0x010601 SATA controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/power/control = auto (0x0c0500 SMBus)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control = auto (0x028000 Network controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/power/control = auto (0x020000 Ethernet controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0/power/control = auto (0x0c0330 USB controller)

+++ USB
tlp usb autosuspend = enabled
tlp usb blacklist   = (not configured)

Bus 001 Device 004 ID 2232:1024 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- <unknown> (no driver)
Bus 001 Device 002 ID 8087:0024 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub (hub)
Bus 001 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 003 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0003 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 002 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)
```

Comment: Try http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107703/why-is-my-pc-freezing-while-im-copying-a-file-to-a-pendrive ... could happen each time you have devices with very different write speeds.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have done all hardware related tests on the HDD, I'd test the system with TLP disabled. Do you see the same symptoms after you set `TLP_ENABLE=0` and reboot?

If so, then TLP settings might be the culprit. I can see you posted the output when system was running on battery, so I am following your lead here :-)

a) I'd increase CPU frequencies some ticks, as I see you are being very conservative. I'd set, for example:

```
CPU_SCALING_MIN_FREQ_ON_BAT=782000
CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_BAT=1300000
```

for all cores.

b) I'd set

```
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT=medium_power
```

and test again.

c) Also, using gnome-disks (the "Disks" application) try enabling Write Cache: select your HDD, click the gear icon on top right, select Drive Settings, and enable there.

There are some more things to do I am sure...good luck.